# Android toolbar inside appbar : All menu is showing at left side always

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am using AppCompatActivity, I have used below layout file and menu, but strangely all menu icons text are being left aligned always. I wan't to show them as usual, i.e back arrow at left and other menu items at right.

My layout file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:theme="@style/CCIAppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/crop_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="60dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/CCIAppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/crop_image_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/result_image_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:translationZ="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[screenshot : all menu items are showing at left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q5q4.png)

Comment: Make `ToolBar` width as `match_parent`

Comment: Thanks! It fixed for me! Interestingly, I found it myself then came here and saw your comment, it's good to see that I did it right way. Thanks again for your correct response. :)